# how to find the first repeated occurance of the character inside the same string in c

Tags: c++, c

How do I get the first occurance of the repeated character to print only that character.it doesnt matter with it should be case sensitive or insensitive.
e.g For input= "opuott" Answer=o/O
        input= "kuttu" Answer=t/T

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
        int i,j,diff=0,min=0;
        char arr[100],var;
        printf("Enter the string to check for: ");
        scanf("%s",&arr);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
                arr[i]=toupper(arr[i]);
                printf("%c ",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++){
                for(j=i+1;j<strlen(arr);j++){
                        if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                                diff=j-i;
                                //THIS IF BLOCK IS USED FOR FIRST CONDITION FAILURE OF MIN AND DIFFERENCE       
                                if(diff > min){
                                        min=diff;
                                        var=arr[i];
                                }
                                //THIS ELSE BLOCK IS USED FOR REGULAR CHECK FOR THE MIN AND DIFF AND ADJUST MIN TO DIFF ACCORDINGLY
                                else if(diff < min){
                                        min=diff;
                                        var=arr[i];
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("Final Answer : %c\n",var);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: For simplicity, let's assume you done care about extended character sets and are only considering 8-bit characters.  You only need to store 256 bits.  For coding simplicity, make it an array of 256 char.  Read one character and indicate in the array that it was read.  Read the next character.  If it has already been seen, generate output.  Otherwise, make an entry in the array.  Looping through the word for each character is wasted effort.

Comment: Which language, C **or** C++?  They are two different languages.  The C++ has `std::string` type and C only has character arrays.  In C++ you can use operator '==' to compare strings; in C you need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should use `std::string` and `std::getline`, to prevent buffer overflow.  The `scanf` function needs to be limited so you don't overflow your character array.

Comment: You may want to assign the result of `strlen` to a constant variable so that the `strlen` function is not called in each iteration.  Remember that `strlen` counts each character in the character array to determine the length.  This usually adds more processing time to your loops.  Caveat:  compilers may do this for you depending on the optimization level.

Comment: You `if-else-if` is missing the final `else` clause where `diff == min`.

Comment: Why is the answer for `kuttu` a `t` instead of `u`?  The `u` is the first letter that is repeated, see your first example.

Comment: hey Thomas thanks for the comments but eg."kuttu" is the one which I am facing the problem and that one is my real requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C,a case sensitive solution can be something like this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    int repeated_char(char arr[],bool char_arr[],size_t len){
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<len;i++){
             if (char_arr[arr[i]] == true)
                 return arr[i];
             else
                 char_arr[arr[i]] = true;
        }
       return -1;
    }

    int main(){

       char arr[100];
       bool char_arr [256];

       printf("Enter the string to check for: ");
      scanf("%100s",&arr);
      size_t arr_len = strlen(arr);
      memset(char_arr,false,sizeof(char_arr));
      char ans = repeated_char(arr,char_arr,arr_len);
      if (ans == -1)
          printf("No repeated chars were found");
      else
          printf("%c",ans);
    }
```

Input:"**n**abc-=1**n**abc"

Output:n

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
std::string input;
std::cin>>input;
std::regex re("(.).*\\1");
std::smatch m;
if (std::regex_search(input,m,re)){
    std::cout << "Repeated " << m[0].str()[0] << "\n";
else
    std::cout << "No repeat\n";
```